# How to show a sidebar conditionally, based on the routing used?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I have a sidebar that will rotate its content based on where the user is (amongst others; in reality also on who the user is, how far her profile is finished and so on).

What I want is a helper that checks against the controller, action and id of the current page.

- *if* the controller is `JobsController` *and* the action is `show` or `index`,  use partial `_sidebar_add_your_job`.
- *if* the controller is `UsersController` *and* the action is `show` or `index`, use partial `_sidebar_add_your_cv`.

The simplified version of my helper, in `app/helpers/sidebar_helper.rb` is:

```
module SidebarHelper
  def sidebar_partial
    if partial
      return "sidebar_#{partial}"
    end
  end

  # Determines what sidebar partial to render.
  def partial
    partial = nil

    if ((section == :jobseekers) && current_user.nil?)
      partial = :add_cv
    elsif ((section == :employers) && current_user.nil?)
      partial = :add_job
    end

    partial
  end

  def section url = nil
    url = request.fullpath if url.nil?

    section = nil

    if (url == root_path || url.match(/^\/jobs/) )
      section = :jobseekers
    elsif (url.match(/^\/employer/) || url.match(/\/users\/[a-z0-9]+/) )
      section = :employers
    end
    section
  end
end
```

Especially the last part, where I match regular expresssions against urls is ugly and fails for quite a few cases. Most notably: `users/sign_in`, users/sign_up` and such. I am relucatant to start maintaining an entire blacklist of these exceptions, it feels too ugly and too tightly coupled to the routes.

How can I best achieve some conditional partial inclusion based on the URL, or controller&action and -in future- on a few more simple conditions such as the role and status of the current user?

How can I test against Controller and its action of the current page/request in a helper?

Comment: please check http://www.postal-code.com/mrhappy/blog/2007/01/18/rails-knowing-the-current-action-in-a-view/ and tell if it's sth you're looking for

Comment: You basically don't care whats after /users/ so your regexp can be easily improved. Also, you should have @controller variable available in all views and helpers (to play with).

Comment: @Bohdan, that is indeed the solution I am looking for: far easier then I though. If you paste it as answer, I can accept it. thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check [this](http://www.postal-code.com/mrhappy/blog/2007/01/18/rails-knowing-the-current-action-in-a-view/) post there you can find an easy way to make current controller and action available in your views